# Array stores duplicate elements even after excluding them

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, arrays, array.prototype.map

I try to dynamically add elements to an Array. If the element in the Array exists, skip it, if it does not exist, add it. The console.log within the .map() function shows, that values have been added. However, it adds too many.

recipes.js

```
const getUniqueTags = async (req,res)=>{
    const allRecipes = await Recipe.find({}).select("tag");
    let resultArray =[];
    resultArray = allRecipes.map( recipe =>{
        const tag = recipe.tag;
        if(resultArray.includes(tag)){
            
        }
        else{
            return tag;
        }
    });

    console.log(resultArray);
    res.status(200).json(resultArray)
}
```

console.log

```
[ Breakfast, Lunch, Lunch, Breakfast ]
```

What am I doing wrong? Includes does not work, neither does new Set()

Comment: Please do not update your question with the solution, it would no longer be clear why it was not working and the answers to the question would get invalidated. You can [write an answer yourself](/help/self-answer) if you want to show your own solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not updating `resultArray` during the `map()` loop. So `resultArray.includes(tag)` is always false, so you do `return tag` every time.

Use a `Set` instead of an array, it automatically removes duplicates.

```
let resultSet = new Set(allRecipes.map(r => r.tag));
```

If you want an array, you can convert it at the end:

```
let resultArray = [...resultSet];
```

```js
const allRecipes = [{
  tag: "Breakfast"
}, {
  tag: "Lunch",
}, {
  tag: "Dinner",
}, {
  tag: "Breakfast"
}];

let resultSet = new Set(allRecipes.map(r => r.tag));
let resultArray = [...resultSet];
console.log(resultArray);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Barmar. When I literally copy and paste your solution to replace my faulty code, it results in the same...
let resultArray = new Set(allRecipes.map( recipe => recipe.tag)) is the code in recipes.js
[ Breakfast, Lunch, Lunch, Breakfast ] is the console.log

Comment: I've added a runnable snippet showing that it works.

Comment: Check for differences in whitespace. Use `trim()` to remove surrounding whitespce from a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your array while checking duplicates in a set:

```js
const result = allRecipes.reduce((r, {tag}) => (r.set.has(tag) || (r.set.add(tag), r.arr.push(tag)), r), {set: new Set, arr:[]}).arr;

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
const allRecipes = [{
  tag: "Breakfast"
}, {
  tag: "Lunch",
}, {
  tag: "Dinner",
}, {
  tag: "Breakfast"
}];
</script>
```

It's faster than mapping into a set and converting back to an array, the more the items the faster:

```
` Chrome/118
--------------------------------------------------------
Alexander   1.00x  |  x10000000  873  891  902  905  905
Barmar      1.41x  |   x1000000  123  125  127  134  139
--------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const allRecipes = [
{
  tag: "Breakfast"
}, {
  tag: "Lunch",
}, {
  tag: "Dinner",
}, {
  tag: "Breakfast"
},
{
  tag: "Breakfast"
}, {
  tag: "Lunch",
}, {
  tag: "Dinner",
}, {
  tag: "Breakfast"
},
{
  tag: "Breakfast"
}, {
  tag: "Lunch",
}, {
  tag: "Dinner",
}, {
  tag: "Breakfast"
},
{
  tag: "Breakfast"
}, {
  tag: "Lunch",
}, {
  tag: "Dinner",
}, {
  tag: "Breakfast"
},
];

// @benchmark Barmar
[...new Set(allRecipes.map(r => r.tag))];


// @benchmark Alexander

allRecipes.reduce((r, {tag}) => (r.set.has(tag) || (r.set.add(tag), r.arr.push(tag)), r), {set: new Set, arr:[]}).arr;

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Answer (score 0):

For Simple array you can use

`const uniqueArray=[...new Set(array)];`

for Array of objects

```js
const uniqueArray = array.filter((item, index) => {
     return index === array.findIndex(obj => obj['key'] === item['key'])
});

console.log(uniqueArray);
```

```html
<script>
const array  = [{
  key: "Breakfast"
}, {
  key: "Lunch",
}, {
  key: "Dinner",
}, {
  key: "Breakfast"
}];
</script>
```

Comment: doesn't work....

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev the solution does work, the issue was with the code snippet inserted, there was a mismatch/typo in object's key. Fixed it already